# Error when migrating: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "primary_language_id" contains null values

Tags: python, django, migrate

I am working on a Django project and made a model with several instances of a models.ForeignKey with the same Model.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    primary_language = models.ForeignKey('Language', related_name='primary_language', default="")
    secondary_language = models.ForeignKey('Language', related_name='secondary_language', default="")
    tertiary_language = models.ForeignKey('Language', related_name='tertiary_language', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the Language model:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

when doing `$python3 manage.py makemigration base`it works fine, no errors. 
I have put the 2 migration files I think are the most important.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('base', '0002_country_country_code'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Currency',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('abbreviation', models.CharField(max_length=3)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Language',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('abbreviation', models.CharField(max_length=2)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='phone_country_code',
            field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=7),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='country',
            name='country_code',
            field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=2),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='primary_language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(to='base.Language', default=''),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='secondary_language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='secondary_language', to='base.Language', default=''),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='tertiary_language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='tertiary_language', to='base.Language', default=''),
        ),
    ]

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('base', '0006_auto_20151023_0918'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='primary_language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='', related_name='primary_language', to='base.Language'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='secondary_language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='', related_name='secondary_language', to='base.Language'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='tertiary_language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='', related_name='tertiary_language', to='base.Language'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='language',
            name='abbreviation',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=2),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='language',
            name='name',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=50),
        ),
    ]
```

Now when running the migration I get an error message I can't figure out. 
I think these are the lines that matter in the stacktrace:

```
johan@johan-pc:~/sdp/gezelligehotelletjes_com$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: auth, base, sessions, admin, contenttypes, hotel
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying base.0003_auto_20151023_0912...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: column "primary_language_id" contains null values


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "primary_language_id" contains null values
```

First of all I do not have a column "primary_language_id" but I guess this is created by Django. Even when deleting the entire Language model and the lines for the languages in the Country model, I still get this error.

Could someone help me with figuring this out?

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: @tapinkoira I have Django version 1.8.5 and I use Python3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already have `Country` objects in your database.

When you add the `primary_language_id` column to them (which represents the `primary_language` `ForeignKey`), those countries end up with an empty `primary_language` (because you didn't specify a default), which throws an error (because you didn't allow empty values either for `primary_language`).

The solution depends on how you want that migration to work. You can add `blank = True` to the `primary_language` `ForeignKey` definition, add a default, or you break down your migration in 3 migrations (add the column with `blank = True`, set values, remove `blank = True`).

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the fast reply. When adding empty=True to the foreignkey defenition I get an error with makemigration, so that would not work. primary_language = models.ForeignKey('Language', related_name='primary_language', empty=True). I already added default="", and now I tried it with default=1, since I refer to ForeignKey which is represented by a number. This also doesn't work.

Comment: @JohanVergeer sorry, it's `blank = True`, not `empty = True`. Make sure you **delete existing migrations and recreate them.** Otherwise your changes won't solve the migration problem (they'll just add more migrations to run afterwards, which won't help).

Comment: I gave that a shot primary_language = models.ForeignKey('Language', related_name='primary_language', default=1) but did not work. Even when commenting out all the language lines in the Country model, I get the same error message. django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "primary_language_id" contains null values

Comment: @JohanVergeer Unless you deleted the migrations and re-ran `makemigrations`, your changes to the model won't make a difference. Did you do that?

Comment: I have deleted all the migrations and reran makemigrations. This still did not work. So I just deleted the database and reinstalled it. Now it works again.

Comment: @JohanVergeer I found after deleting migrations sometimes to avoid further deleting database and starting over I must run `db stamp head`

Comment: @ThomasOrozco thank you for mentioning to delete existing migrations. That is what I needed to do and it helped me solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you had a table created and it was populated, when you try to add it another column Django is like these data already in the table don't have this new field this guy is trying to add and it messes up. What I did was to go to my table and delete all the data. Once I did that I could migrate. If you have a small table this might work, no need to touch migrations.